# ValueError at /users/index/ Ensure you specified correct input image, input type, output type and/or output image path

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I am building of program using OpenCV. I get this `Ensure you specified correct input image, input type, output type and/or output image path` error when I pass a variable through the function. If I mentioned the image path like `"media/image.jpeg"` then everything works properly.

I have tried using manually like `detect("media/image.jpeg")` which works. If I put any variable like `detect('"' + uploaded_file_url + '"')` it doesn't work.

**Views.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .FirstDetection import detect
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
    def index2 (request):
    global name
    global uploaded_file_url 
    name = "name"
    uploaded_file_url = "media/image.jpeg"
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['pic']:
        pic = request.FILES['pic']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(pic.name, pic)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        name = detect("media/image.jpeg")
        mylist = []
        for n in name:
            mylist.append(n)
        return render(request, 'index.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url, 'd2' : mylist
        })

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**Detection.py file**

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os

def detect(image):
        # execution_path = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir("/Users/sifatulshohan/Documents/CSE-327/Django_project/nsu.nbm.summer2019.cse327.1.t3/Django")
        media_path = os.getcwd()
        if os.path.exists("/Users/sifatulshohan/Documents/CSE-327/Django_project/nsu.nbm.summer2019.cse327.1.t3/Django/media") :
                os.chdir("/Users/sifatulshohan/Documents/CSE-327/Django_project/nsu.nbm.summer2019.cse327.1.t3/Django/media")
        execution_path = os.getcwd()
        detector = ObjectDetection()
        detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
        detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
        detector.loadModel()
        url = '"' + "'" + image + "'" + '"'
        detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(media_path , image), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , "imagenew.jpeg"))
        for eachObject in detections:
                name = eachObject["name"]
                # probability = eachObject["percentage_probability"]
                if(eachObject["percentage_probability"] > 80):
                        yield(name)
```

**Html Form**

```
<form method="post" action= "{% url 'index' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% comment %} <input type = "text" name= "name"> {% endcomment %}
    <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Upload Image">
</form>
{% if uploaded_file_url %}
    <p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{ uploaded_file_url }}">{{ uploaded_file_url }}</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

I get proper output when pass argument like `detect("media/image.jpeg")`, otherwise gets error.

Comment: Why are you adding `"` to the string? Your method requires a string, so just `detect(uploaded_file_url)` should work.

Comment: uploaded_file_url value is already string but When I manually put the string value with quote it works. So I tried in both ways using the variable and also by putting '"' string. But none of them works.

Comment: show us your full error trace. Also, `print(image)` and `print(media_path)` to check what the path is that you're passing to the detector.